# Can not open file in C

Tags: c, file, io

This is my code for opening a file where the inputs are given below.
The program is going to read the file and calculate the average of the last column. But every time I run the program i get an output saying "failed to open file". I am not able to figure out the problem with my code.

```
Input
3   11  12  05  1   8.7
3   11  11  56  143 8.6
3   11  13  01  163 8.9
3   10  18  05  1   7.3

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
  FILE *myfile,*output_file;

  int month,day,timeHour,timeMinute,stnNumber;
  float temperature;
  float sumTemp=0;
  float AverageTemp=0;

  myfile=fopen("Input_file.txt","r");
  //read through line by line
  if(myfile==NULL){
    printf("Failed to open file\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  output_file=fopen("average_sum.txt","w");

  if(output_file==NULL)
  {
    printf("The file was not opened.");
    exit(1);
  }
  while(fscanf(myfile,"%d %d %d %d %d %.2f", 
        &month,&day,&timeHour,&timeMinute,&stnNumber,&temperature) != EOF){
    sumTemp+=temperature;
    AverageTemp=sumTemp/4;
    fprintf(output_file,"%.2f\n",AverageTemp);
  }
  fclose(myfile);
  fclose(output_file);
}
```

Comment: Instead of `printf("Failed to open file\n");`, call `perror("Input_file.txt");`. At least you will know _why_ you cannot open the file.

Comment: And error messages should be printed to `stderr` with `fprintf(stderr, ...`

Comment: Are you running executable from the same directory where the input file present.

Comment: As a side note: Since the problem happens  on line 12, there is no point to post the remaining 20+ lines. Keep your example minimal.

Comment: It's an odds-on bet that the data file you're looking to open isn't in the directory where you are running your program from.  If you've got an IDE at work running the code for you, you'll definitely do better specifying the absolute pathname of the file as an argument to the program, and pass that to your `fopen()` call.  Make sure your error message includes the file name and the reason.  (IMO, `perror()` isn't adequate, but it is better than nothing — and better than what you've currently got.)  You might also end up needing to print the current working directory (see `getcwd()`).

Comment: yes i am running it in the same directory

Comment: As DyZ already said use [perror](https://linux.die.net/man/3/perror) and you will probably know what the problem is

Comment: My guess is, the name "Input_file.txt" does not match with the name of the file in the directory character by character. Get rid of the capital letter.